# Pass method to reduce/inject instead of block

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to pass a method to reduce or inject instead of block like this:

```
def super_process(list, item)
  list ||= []
  list << another_method(item) + just_another_method
end

arr = ['1', '2', '3']
arr.reduce(&method(:super_process))
```

I have a problem with handling of `list` (it's default value). It's assigned to the first element of `arr` on first iteration but on next iteration it's assigned to the result of the first one.
I know I can write:

```
arr.reduce {|list, item| list << another_method(list, item) }
```

But that seems quite long and inexpressive to me.

Comment: The code here is not easily reproducible and is too ambiguous.  Please clarify the code block with code that can be easily tested.

Comment: @Eugene sorry, I did this because I didn't want my example to be solved but wanted a pointer to the right direction. And I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your example is due to not passing the initial value to `reduce`. From [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

> ```
> reduce { |memo, obj| block } → obj
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the
>   first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

Therefore you probably want to pass an array as the first argument. I've changed the definition of `super_process` to something simpler:

```
def super_process list, item
    list.push item + 1
end

arr = [1, 2, 3]
res = arr.reduce [], &method(:super_process)
puts res
```

This will output

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before and thought it didn't work, It works!)